# I have a docker alphine container however all curl calls fails with curl: (6) Could not resolve host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**My Dockerfile configuration is below:**

For example a CURL to `api.sendgrid.com` fails like this:

> *Uncaught SendGrid\Exception\InvalidRequest: Could not send request to server. CURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api.sendgrid.com in /var/www/html/vendor/sendgrid/php-http-client/lib/Client.php:472*

```
ARG APACHE_VERSION=""
FROM httpd:${APACHE_VERSION:+${APACHE_VERSION}-}alpine
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;
RUN apk add \
  bash \
  apache2 \
  php7-apache2 \
  curl \
  ca-certificates \
  openssl \
  git \
  php7 \
  php7-phar \
  php7-json \
  php7-iconv \
  php7-openssl \
  tzdata \
  openntpd \
  php7-ftp \
  php7-xdebug \
  php7-mcrypt \
  php7-mbstring \
  php7-soap \
  php7-gmp \
  php7-pdo_odbc \
  php7-dom \
  php7-pdo \
  php7-zip \
  php7-mysqli \
  php7-sqlite3 \
  php7-bcmath \
  php7-gd \
  php7-odbc \
  php7-pdo_mysql \
  php7-pdo_sqlite \
  php7-gettext \
  php7-xmlreader \
  php7-xmlwriter \
  php7-tokenizer \
  php7-xmlrpc \
  php7-bz2 \
  php7-pdo_dblib \
  php7-curl \
  php7-ctype \
  php7-session \
  php7-exif;
RUN sed -i "s/#LoadModule\ rewrite_module/LoadModule\ rewrite_module/" /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf;
# COPY .bashrc /root/.bashrc
# Copy apache vhost file to proxy php requests to php-fpm container
COPY demo.apache.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/demo.apache.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

A restart of the docker container fixed it.

Comment: May I add that the issue was deeper has the build I was using was not properly configured. I eventually switched to ubuntu 18.xx image